# Script parse error on select distinct in Documentum

Tags: documentum-dql

need expert advice here with regards to running Documentum DQL.

I'm getting an error when running script below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TRIM(a.r_gen_source), '|', TRIM(a.user_name), '|', TRIM(a.time_stamp), '|', TRIM(d.object_name) FROM dm_audittrail a, dm_document d WHERE time_stamp>=Date('01/01/2023', 'mm/dd/yyyy') and time_stamp<=Date('01/31/2023', 'mm/dd/yyyy') and a.audited_obj_id=d.r_object_id ORDER BY time_stamp ASC
```

go

See error code below:

```
[DM_QUERY_E_SYNTAX]error: "A Parser Error (syntax error) has occurred in the vicinity of: SELECT DISTINCT TRIM("
```

Answer (score 1):

well, it is quite clear, if you read the DQL reference guide you'll see that TRIM is not a valid function in DQL, that's why it is failing at the trim statement